# Formatting the output printing in the console in java

Tags: java

I can't find the correct format for printing the output to the console using `System.out.format()` my code is

```
System.out.format("%03d%-15s%18d%n",ID[i],name[i],salary[i]);
```

The formatting code(using left indentation) is not providing perfect output as expected.

```
============================================
               Employee Details             
============================================
     ID          Name            Salary     
============================================
001john                        12000
002clark                       13000
003nancy                       14000
004joe                         15000
005mark                        17000
```

This code is without indentation, and its output is

```
System.out.format("%03d%15s%18d%n",ID,name,salary);

============================================
               Employee Details             
============================================
     ID          Name            Salary     
============================================
001           john             10000
002         markus             12000
003          clark             14000
004          nancy             13000
005            joe             14000
```

But the desired output is

```
============================================
               Employee Details             
============================================
     ID          Name            Salary     
============================================
    001          john            10000
    002          markus          12000
    003          clark           14000
    004          nancy           13000
    005          joe             14000
```

Can somebody point out how should the formatter can changed to get the above mentioned desired output so that every variable is left indented.

Comment: Why not use just `\t`?

Comment: Use the same formatter you use in the loop for printing employee details, as you use with ` ID          Name            Salary` (the string literals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tab `(\t)` for Formatting the output printing in the console in java.

Like :

```
System.out.format("%03d\t\t\t%-15s\t\t\t%18d\t\t\t%n",ID[i],name[i],salary[i]);
```